# dependant subquery processed despite Extra Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables

Tags: mysql

in this query https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/snzSLd8y1oRNRqdsFpNdHa/0

```
SELECT test0.id,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(test2.one_info) FROM test2 WHERE test2.one_id = test1.id) AS GC
FROM test0
INNER JOIN test1 ON test1.zero_id = test0.id
WHERE test0.id = 1 AND test1.id = 1 AND test1.rand = 5;
```

`test1.rand=5` exists so the execution plan is

```
| id  | select_type        | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
| --- | ------------------ | ----- | ---------- | ----- | ------------- | ------- | ------- | ----- | ---- | -------- | ----------- |
| 1   | PRIMARY            | test0 |            | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const | 1    | 100      | Using index |
| 1   | PRIMARY            | test1 |            | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const | 1    | 100      |             |
| 2   | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | test2 |            | ref   | IND           | IND     | 5       | const | 4    | 100      | Using index |
```

but when i change it to something that does not exist like `test1.rand=10` it give this exectuion plan

```
| id  | select_type        | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra                                               |
| --- | ------------------ | ----- | ---------- | ---- | ------------- | --- | ------- | ----- | ---- | -------- | --------------------------------------------------- |
| 1   | PRIMARY            |       |            |      |               |     |         |       |      |          | Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables |
| 2   | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | test2 |            | ref  | IND           | IND | 5       | const | 4    | 100      | Using index                                         |
```

and despite `Extra: Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables` and it returning no results it still used `select_type: DEPENDANT SUBQUERY` and got `rows: 4`

how to fix this problem and make it not return anything at all to save performance?

Comment: I don't see the problem, there are no records that the selct can choose from, because you filtert them all out in your where clause.

Comment: @nbk but the `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY` still got rows in the execution plan

Comment: as P.Salmin explain. Frits the From select all rows, the the where filters the rows, with test1.rand = 10 there are now rows left, so Select doesn't hsow any., it doesn't matter hat ais in the subquery, because it willonly be run if there is a row for test2.one_id = test1.id) to run , but as you see in the explain there isn't any
'

Comment: @nbk so despite the subquery showing me `rows: 5` it is just a text and it didn't do anything to lower the performance?

Comment: No, it had checked the subquery, but fell short because it has no vaules to check. I the first  run mysql tries to optimize the given query and will check everything out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Handler counts to see if it is actually touching any rows:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts

And use `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` to get more details.

Anyway, since it is a *DEPENDENT* subquery, it will be asked to run as often as needed.  But that is zero times.

Also, `EXPLAIN`, is not perfect.  The subquery did not get 4 rows; `EXPLAIN` is *estimating* that it will touch 4 rows each time it the subquery is invoked.  Again, 0*4 = 0.